# UI freezing while executing async command (AvaloniaUI + ReactiveUI)

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I am trying to create a MVVM Avalonia app using the ReactiveUi and want to execute a command async in order to keep the user interface working. However this is not the case. After hitting my button, the ui freezes until the command has finished executing even though i am running it async.

Does somebody know, what i am doing wrong here?

This is what i am currently doing:

**ViewModel:**

```
public LoginViewModel()
{
    TryConnectAsyncCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(TryConnectAndLogin);
}

public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> TryConnectAsyncCommand { get; }

async Task TryConnectAndLogin()
{
    ErrorFlag = false;
    ClientConversationManager.TryConnect(EnteredInstance, EnteredPort);
    if (ClientConversationManager.IsConnected)
    {
            
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorFlagContent = "Could not connect to server :/";
        ErrorFlag = true;
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
Command="{Binding TryConnectAsyncCommand}"
```

Comment: There are no `await`s in your function. Perhaps there should be something like `await ClientConversationManager.TryConnectAsync(` or similar

Comment: Making the other functions async and awaiting them sadly does not solve my problem. Also why can't i just await the entire `TryConnectAndLogin`?

Comment: No it will block the thread unless you have an `await`. Marking it `async` doesn't magically do anything until you have an `await`

Comment: So i awaited the other functions but it sadly did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `TryConnectAndLogin` is synchronized. You can make it async using `Task.Run` (standard way) or `Observable.Start` (rx way).

```
public LoginViewModel()
{
    TryConnectAsyncCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(TryConnectAndLogin);
}

public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> TryConnectAsyncCommand { get; }

private IObservable<Unit> TryConnectAndLogin()
{
    return Observable.Start(() =>
    {
        ErrorFlag = false;
        ClientConversationManager.TryConnect(EnteredInstance, EnteredPort);
        if (ClientConversationManager.IsConnected)
        {
                
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorFlagContent = "Could not connect to server :/";
            ErrorFlag = true;
        }
    });
}
```